# How to Check Two String Using Guava?

Tags: java, google-api, guava

I wrote a java code to check two string  `if("SS".equalsIgnoreCase("Xx"))` but My code analyzer suggest me to use Google API Guava. Any of you know how to do? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point in pulling in a library just to do basic comparisons which are supported by the native String object.

Comment: I love to go with the basic comparison, but Code code analyzer push me to go with Guava,

Comment: WTF is this analyzer?

Comment: I  also feel the same when it ask me to go with Guava..

Comment: Time to change company and work with some better people,*IMHO*

Comment: comparing the performance guava is better than basic string comparison.

Comment: I'm quite sure your analyzer must be from Google itself, producer of Guava ^^ Now just wonder if it's not an advert from Google ;)

Comment: @Julien: I don't believe they'd do this. It makes no sense... there are many places where using Guava is a big win, so why to advertise with such a non-sense? Moreover, there's nothing to gain as Guava is free.

Comment: @maaartinus I believe they could, I don't know if it's the case. But you're wrong when you say there's nothing to gain : Google loves having people walking in his footprints :)

Comment: If there's anything you should be using instead of `String.equalsIgnoreCase`, it's in ICU4J, not Guava.

Answer (score 2):

Guava is intended to provide utilities not in the basic JDK.  This, clearly, is in the basic JDK.  Guava doesn't have anything for this case at *all.*

There *is* no "Guava way" to do this.  This entire discussion is nonsensical.

(That doesn't mean there aren't strong arguments for using Guava in the cases where it *does* have utilities that can help for a given use case, but this is not one of those cases.)

Answer (score 1):

Heavily recommending

```
 Str1.equalsIgnoreCase( Str2)
```

Since I don't see any requirment of using a third party library.

That string method have a lready a perfect method to do it.

Your analyzer might expecting some argument like this from you :)

Just say **NO**,Since you have readly avaialble methods from String class. Just ask **Why??**

Comment: Well, this is some things my code analyzer push me...

Comment: @stacktome Just ask to your analyzer that Why I have to use that ? I bet, you won't get any answer from him.

Comment: yap correct. I'm tired of asking the same question several time. Its seams analyzer believe google than me.. another things ppl always promoted there product this way too

Comment: Use string class method and pass this questions link to your so called analyzer. :D

Comment: comparing the performance guava is better than basic string comparison.

Comment: @stacktome I'd say native java have high preference than Gauva. whats up ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If he only trust Google, audit your code with CodePro Analytix (if you don't use the latest Eclipse version :s ).

There will be nothing to change to your code.
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit

Comment: Héhé ;) It's just because Guava didn't exist at the time of CodePro maybe ^^

Comment: Probably ;) @stacktome can you tell us which method of guava your code analyzer recommends?